# Custom menu with drupal_get_form plus form_alter_hook

Tags: routes, forms

I'm working in Drupal 6 to create a custom module. I have a menu that creates some custom URLs and tabs for me, and each item runs a page callback function, which itself runs `drupal_get_form`.

What I'm observing is that this process does not run `mymodule_form_name_alter`. While this makes sense, I'd like to achieve both of these ends.

Here's some of what I currently have:

```
function module_accounts_menu() {

  $items['user/%user/preferences'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Preferences',
    'page callback'    => 'module_accounts_category_form',
    'page arguments' => array('preferences'),
    'access callback'  => 'module_accounts_edit_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file'             => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path'        => 'modules/user',
    'weight' => 1
  );

  return $items;
}

function module_accounts_category_form($category = 'account') {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
  return drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account, $category);  
}

function module_accounts_edit_access(){
  global $user;
  return user_edit_access($user);
}

function module_form_formid_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
drupal_set_message('tes');
$form['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'user');

// some more stuff that does not happen
```

}

So basically, it's really helpful for me to have the custom menu links, but not at the expense of my form hooks. Is it possible for me to have both of these?

Thanks.